# using openlayers and google maps, the mouse cursor and the dot on the map not inline

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, wms

i'm trying to implement the example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/drag-feature.html .

When i'm implementing this with a Google map, I have a strange bug: the mouse pointer and the dot on the map are not in the same place.

Now if I change the line that in bold:  map.addLayers([gmap,vectors]); to map.addLayers([wms,vectors]); everything works. (in other words I dont use google maps).

Can someone tell me what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my page and code:

```
   var map;
   var vectors;
   function initialize() {
       // Create the map object
       map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        //Create a Google layer
       var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Streets", // the default
           {numZoomLevels: 20}
       );
      // if i use this instead of gmap then everything works.
       var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});
       var renderer=OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
       renderer=(renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

       vectors= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer",{
           renderers:renderer
       });

       map.addLayers([gmap,vectors]);

       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

       var control=new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors,OpenLayers.Handler.Path);
       map.addControl(control);
       control.activate();
       // Zoom to Vancouver, BC
       map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-123.12, 49.28), 13);         
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not really sure what you mean. All works fine for me. See my [example](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/drag.html) with your code.

Comment: Can you show the HTML for how you actually retrieve the lat/long values on your map? Thank you.